# Notice: Undefined index: variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache

I'm trying to build a simple form with drop-down lists to query my database (designed for a library for an afterschool program). The idea is that the drop-down lists are populated by the names of books or students, so that when you select a name and Submit, the database selects details with a matching foreign key from the table.

Problem is, whenever I open up the form, I get several copies of these lines above the form:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\CMPS\Library\query\index.php on line 88
>
> Notice: Undefined index: name in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\CMPS\Library\query\index.php on line 88
>
> Notice: Undefined index: isbn in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\CMPS\Library\query\index.php on line 104
>
> Notice: Undefined index: title in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\CMPS\Library\query\index.php on line 104

Likewise, each of the drop-down lists says either

> Notice: Undefined index: name in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\CMPS\Library\query\searchform.html.php on line 20

or

> Notice: Undefined index: title in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\CMPS\Library\query\searchform.html.php on line 30

***index.php***

```
<?php include_once 
'../includes/helpers.inc.php';

require_once '../access.inc.php';

if (!userIsLoggedIn())
{
    include '../login.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (!userHasRole('Verified'))
{
    $error = 'Only verified accounts may access this page.';
    include '../accessdenied.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['action']) and $_GET['action'] == 'search')
{
  include '../includes/db.inc.php';

  $select = 'SELECT CONCAT_WS(\' \', student.First, student.Last) as Name, book.Title, checkout.Checked, checkout.Due';
  $from   = ' FROM checkout, student, book';
  $where  = ' WHERE student.ID = checkout.StudentID AND book.ISBN = checkout.BookISBN';

  $placeholders = array();

  if ($_GET['student'] != '') 
  {
    $where .= " AND checkout.StudentID = :studentid";
    $placeholders[':studentid'] = $_GET['student'];
  } 

  if ($_GET['book'] != '') 
  {
    $where .= " AND checkout.BookISBN = :bookisbn";
    $placeholders[':bookisbn'] = $_GET['book'];
  } 

  if (isset($_POST['ongoing']) && $_POST['ongoing'] == 'Yes') 
  { 
    $where .= " AND Ongoing = 1";
  } 

  try
  {
    $sql = $select . $from . $where;
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->execute($placeholders);
  }
  catch (PDOException $e)
  { 
    $error = 'Error fetching checkouts.';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
  }

  foreach ($s as $row)
  { 
    $checkouts[] = array('Name' => $row['name'], 'book.Title' => $row['title'], 
                         'Checked' => $row['checked'], 'Due' => $row['due']);
  } 

  include 'query.html.php';
  exit();
}

include '../includes/db.inc.php';

try
{ 
  $result = $pdo->query('SELECT ID, CONCAT_WS(\' \', First, Last) as Name FROM student');
} 
catch (PDOException $e)
{ 
  $error = 'Error fetching students from database!';
  include 'error.html.php';
  exit();
}

foreach ($result as $row)
{ 
  $students[] = array('ID' => $row['id'], 'Name' => $row['name']); #Line 88
} 

try
{ 
  $result = $pdo->query('SELECT ISBN, Title FROM book');
} 
catch (PDOException $e)
{ 
  $error = 'Error fetching books from database!';
  include 'error.html.php';
  exit();
}

foreach ($result as $row)
{ 
  $books[] = array('ISBN' => $row['isbn'], 'Title' => $row['title']); #Line 104
} 

include 'searchform.html.php';
```

***searchform.html.php***

```
<?php include_once 
'../includes/helpers.inc.php';  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- <link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> -->
    <title>Query Checkouts</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Query</h1>
    <form action="" method="get">
      <p>View checkouts satisfying the following criteria:</p>
      <div>
        <label for="student">By student:</label>
        <select name="student" id="student">
          <option value="">Any student</option>
          <?php foreach ($students as $student): ?>
            <option value="<?php htmlout($student['id']); ?>"><?php
                htmlout($student['name']); ?></option> <!-- Line 20 -->
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div> 
        <label for="book">By book:</label>
        <select name="book" id="book">
          <option value="">Any book</option>
          <?php foreach ($books as $book): ?>
            <option value="<?php htmlout($book['isbn']); ?>"><?php
                htmlout($book['title']); ?></option> <!-- Line 30 -->
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="ongoing">Ongoing only?:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ongoing" value="Yes" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
      </div>
    </form>
    <p><a href="..">Return to PHL home</a></p>
    <?php include '../logout.inc.html.php'; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried checking the code, but phpcodechecker.com says there are zero errors, and I'm having a hard time using Chrome Logger to debug.

Hoping I can understand what I'm doing wrong so I won't make the mistake later in development!

Comment: you also mix html and php to often, its not readable, dont do code like this `<option value="<?php htmlout($book['isbn']); ?>"><?php
                htmlout($book['title']); ?></option> <!-- Line 30 -->
          <?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure to use case-sensitive indices when accessing the `$row` in your loop.

Change:

```
$students[] = array('ID' => $row['id'], 'Name' => $row['name']);
```

To:

```
$students[] = array('ID' => $row['ID'], 'Name' => $row['Name']);
```

Additionally, in `searchform.html.php` you need to access your arrays as you have defined them, ie. use `ID` and `Name` to access those values. Or change those indices in the above alteration to match the expected lowercase versions.

Example:

```
$students[] = array('id' => $row['ID'], 'name' => $row['Name']);
```

---

Just so you know, this may be affecting the other result loops too. Just apply the same changes to those as well and you should be fine (eg. `$checkouts` appears to also be affected).